# In Pure Data is there any way to track down a "signal outlet connect to nonsignal inlet (ignored)" error?

Tags: puredata

I have a Pd patch which calls in a second patch as an abstraction.

The second patch works fine by itself. But when I try to use it from inside the first, I'm seeing this

```
signal outlet connect to nonsignal inlet (ignored)
```

error. But I can't see WHERE it's happening.

Doing "Find last error" just gives me.

```
... sorry, I couldn't find the source of that error.
```

How can I find out which two objects Pd is referring to with that outlet / inlet?

(The outlets of the subpatches are being wired into `[dac~]` in the main patch)

These subpatches USED TO work, until I tried to add Open Sound Control to them with udpreceive. And, like I say, they still do work, accepting the OSC if I run them on their own.

Comment: One place pure data is weak is automatically finding the source of errors. But that one's usually visible if we can see the patch.~

Could I see a screenshot of the patch, please?

Answer (score 4):

actually, Pd (>=0.43) became quite good at locating the source of errors, but unfortunately this is little known (and less documented).

if you get a *findable* error (usually those in red; and the error you get is one of them!), you can <kbd>click</kbd> on the error-line and it will take you to the object that complained (and select it)

the actual click-sequence is OS-dependent:

- linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LeftMouseButton</kbd>
- w32 : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LeftMouseButton</kbd>
- OSX : <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>LeftMouseButton</kbd>

alternatively you can get to the error, by clicking on the error-message and then hitting

- <kbd>Return</kbd>

(<kbd>Enter</kbd> should work as well).

Comment: Fantastic!! I can't believe I didn't find your post earlier... this could have saved me so much hassle! Many thanks